# Multi arguments to CALLBACK in addEventListener in the FOR statement is difficult

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

---

## For loop generates Button

---

I wanted to generate dynamic amount button.
And wanted to recognize which one was clicked.
This is real code...

```
for(var col:int = 1; col <= MaxColumn; col++){
  for(var row:int = 1; row <= MaxRow; row++){
    makeGrid(col, row);
    Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row] = new Button();
    Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].label = col + "行" + row + "列" ;
    Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].setStyle("fontSize", 10);
    Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].setStyle("cornerRadius", 0);
    Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].x = 1150 - 500/MaxRow * (row - 1);
    Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].y = 150 + 500/MaxColumn * (col - 1);
    Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].width = 500/MaxRow;
    Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].height = 500/MaxColumn;
    Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].setStyle("color", 0x191970);
    Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].setStyle("fontSize", 7);
    Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onGridClick(col, row));
    rootPanel.addElement(Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row]);
  }
}

private function onGridClick(col, row):void{
  makeGridId(col, row);
  return function(event:Event):void{
    var createGridDialog:CreateGridDialog = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, CreateGridDialog, true) asCreateGridDialog;
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(createGridDialog);
    createGridDialog.setGridId(globalGridId);
    createGridDialog.setMaxRow(MaxRow);
    createGridDialog.addEventListener(CreateGridEvent.GRID_SUBMIT, tmpSave);
  }
}

public function makeGridId(col:int, row:int):void{
  globalGridId = (col - 1) * MaxRow + row;
}
```

---

## addEventListener's callback function is difficult

---

Because, in

```
private function onGridClick(col, row):void{
```

,

```
  makeGridId(col, row);
```

repeated in each for blocks, so globalGridId is overwritten in the end after compile.(row = MaxRow,col = MaxColumn)
If the callback function could accept col&row directly, this issue would close.
But addEventListener's callback is difficult...

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, **onGridClick**)
```

The callback basically accept only one argument:MouseEvent directly, and only return void type.

I want to make globalGridId when I click, and I want to send it to where I click.

How should I do?

---

## I Notice

---

please see this...

```
<s:Button id="Grid1" x="220" y="0" width="80" height="80" click="onSubClick(event, 0)"/>

private function onSubClick(event:MouseEvent, division:int):void {
  var subSymbolDialog:SubSymbolDialog = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, SubSymbolDialog, true) as SubSymbolDialog;
  PopUpManager.centerPopUp(subSymbolDialog);
  subSymbolDialog.setDivision(division);
  subSymbolDialog.addEventListener(SubSymbolEvent.SUB_CLOSE, onSubClose);
}
```

this is weird.

```
click="onSubClick(event, 0)"
```

Why this is working?

Comment: If you want to make a grid, why don't you use DataGrid (with item renderers that have a Button)? it has such an event built-in. You could also use a List with a TileLayout to create the Buttons, but that does not have the row/col event built-in.

Comment: `onSubClick(event, 0)` works because the compiler creates its own event listener (which has only one parameter: `event`). This generated event listener then calls your method `onSubClick` with both parameters. You could even write `click="foo(); bar(event, 'hello', 'world'); baz(event)"` and it would still work. When you write an event listener in MXML (like `click`) the compiler takes all the code and puts it inside a generated event listener. You can set the compiler option `keep-generated-actionscript=true` if you want to see the generated code.

Comment: RIAstar> Your suggestion is correct in high probability. This is because I'm newbie of flexAPI so once touch to <mx:DataGrid> but it did't work for dynamic declaration. And I didn't notice about use of DataGrid Class in <fx:Script>. try to do it.

Comment: Gerhard Schlager> Oh, I see. Auto generating of callback's wrapper method explains every question. I don't know why I haven't come to think that... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot pass arguments to listeners callback functions.
Try extends the buttonClass as follow:

```
package
{
    public class MyButton extends Button
    {

        public var row:int;
        public var col:int;

        public function MyButton()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

After that you just have to fill the row and col property for the buttons.

```
for(var col:int = 1; col <= MaxColumn; col++){
    for(var row:int = 1; row <= MaxRow; row++){
        makeGrid(col, row);
        Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row] = new MyButton();
        Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].col = col;
        Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].row = row;
        //...
```

on the callback function you can retrieve it as follow:

```
private function onGridClick(e:Event):void
{
    var b:MyButton = event.target as MyButton;

    makeGridId(b.col, b.row);

    var createGridDialog:CreateGridDialog = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, CreateGridDialog, true) asCreateGridDialog;
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(createGridDialog);
    createGridDialog.setGridId(globalGridId);
    createGridDialog.setMaxRow(MaxRow);
    createGridDialog.addEventListener(CreateGridEvent.GRID_SUBMIT, tmpSave);
}
```

PS: I warn you about the use of your array named Button exactly the same a s the class Button.

If you can use upercase first letters only for class name and keep lowercase first letter for variable, it's better (ex: MyClassName, myVariableName) ;)

Comment: Wow! Class extends is a blind spot! I managed to resolve this by substituting "Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row].id = col + row;" but this is far better!

P.S.
Button["btn_" + col + "_" + row] is not array. This is dynamic valuable declaration. I wanted to generate from btn_1_1 to btw_10_10, Button class.  But according to above comments, DataGrid is far better.